# How to init Bootstrap Popover in Webpack Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-6.1

So I followed the [bootstrap doc on who to init the popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/popovers/#example-enable-popovers-everywhere), but it doesn't work. It threw this error. How do I fix this?

```
Uncaught TypeError: bootstrap.Popover is not a constructor
```

These are the codes.

**test_popover.html**

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" 
          data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
    Click
  </button>
```

**test_popover.js**

```
  ...
  var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
  var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
  })
```

I have import the bootstrap in packs/application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
    

// Import Bootstrap only ones that are used to reduce size
import 'bootstrap';
import '../javascripts/test_popover';
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got it fixed. I import the `Popover` and changed from new `bootstrap.Popover()` to `new Popover()`

```
import Popover from 'bootstrap/js/dist/popover';

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {    
  var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
  var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
  })
});
```